# Arrow shifting from an equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows, draw

My code:

```
\documentclass[42pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[remember picture,inner sep=0pt] \node (#1){};}
\begin{document}
$\mu_{0,\dots,\tikzmark{a}1,\dots,0}$

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[<-] (a.center) to [in=90,out=270]+(270:0.5cm) node[anchor=north] {\emph{i-th} postion};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Ouput:
[image: Output]

Here the arrow is left to 1 but I want to shift it slightly to right just beneath the number 1.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tikzmark` library. It has a much better command for that, `\tikzmarknode`.

```
\documentclass[42pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\begin{document}
$\mu_{0,\dots,\tikzmarknode{a}{1},\dots,0}$

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[<-] ([yshift=-2pt]a.south) -- ++(270:0.5cm) node[anchor=north] {\emph{i-th} postion};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What that `++` do?

Comment: @ChandramauliChakraborty It is similar to a single `+` (and in this application equivalent to it): it adds a coordinate to the last coordinate before it.